# How to find the memory address of a task or a variable in FreeRTOS

Tags: memory-management, microcontroller, freertos, cortex-m, dma

I'm a beginner in the embedded and real-time systems world, so my task is to live patch buggy tasks using DMA,

**My problem is**

> How to find the memory address of my buggy task to analyse it and
>   eventually patch it ?

I'm using FreeRTOS on an EFM32 giant gecko micro-controller and GCC compiler.

Comment: When using [xTaskCreate](http://www.freertos.org/a00125.html) you pass a task handle to the function. Try to investigate if you recieve the address of the task in this handle.

Comment: thanks for your help, but this is the problem, is there any function that I can use so I can find the address

Comment: No there is not 'the one' function. But as I stated, try to investigate what kind of value xTaskCreate writes into the task handle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution for my problem by using the task control block (TCB) of my task, the tskTCB contains many information about the task associated to it, inter alia the Lowest task stack address (pxStack), the Highest task stack address (pxEndOfStack) and the Current top of the task stack (pxTopOfStack).